# How to start pods on demand in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I need to create pods on demand in order to run a program. it will run according to the needs, so it could be that for 5 hours there will be nothing running, and then 10 requests will be needed to process, and I might need to limit that only 5 will run simultaneously because of resources limitations.

I am not sure how to build such a thing in kubernetes.

Also worth noting is that I would like to create a new docker container for each run and exit the container when it ends.

Comment: As long as the main process inside the pod is running, the pod will be up, even if no requests are coming. If you want to serve only 5 requests, that's better be implemented in the application logic, otherwise, if you're referring to the pods' limitation, you can create 5 replicas of the same pod, and ensure that each pod serves only one request at a time.

Comment: Would it work for you to set up a job queue like RabbitMQ, and then create a long-running worker Deployment to handle jobs from the queue?  This would mean you don't need to write any Kubernetes-specific logic, and (with some work) you can configure the Kubernetes HorizontalPodAutoscaler to create more worker replicas when the queue gets long.

Answer (score 4):

There are many options and you’ll need to try them out. The core tool is HorizontalPodAutoscaler. Systems like KEDA build on top of that to manage metrics more easily. There’s also Serverless tools like knative or kubeless. Or workflow tools like Tekton, Dagster, or Argo.

It really depends on your specifics.